# Postfix: What is the meaning of the non-loopback IPv6 addresses in the default value of mynetworks configuration parameter?

Tags: postfix, ipv6

On Postfix 3.1.0, `postconf -d mynetworks` prints:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 [::1]/128 [fd6f:721b:f2ec::]/64 [fe80::]/64
```

What do the last two elements in the list, `[fd6f:721b:f2ec::]/64 [fe80::]/64` represent?  They are not loopback addresses.  Are they private address space?  Any specification reference available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address range `fe80::/64` is the [link-local address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6) range.

The IP address range `fd6f:721b:f2ec::/64` is a subnet in the [unique local address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) range.

Note that this configuration is not what is actually in the postfix main.cf file, but is the end result of configuring postfix. It is listening to all interfaces and networks in your configuration, and this line represents all of the networks configured on your host's interfaces.

Comment: If FE80::/64 is included, any reason why 169.254.0.0/16 is not?

Comment: @ARX It isn't assigned to any of your interfaces.